# Copy a folder using the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, file-transfer, cmd.exe

How can a folder be copied using the `cmd.exe` shell?

Using Explorer, this is easy to do.  Right-click the folder to copy, drag it to the destination folder, and then select "Copy here."

Suppose we have this folder structure:

```
src
  --a.txt
  --b.txt
dest
  --c.txt
  --d.txt
```

How can we get this result:

```
src
  --a.txt
  --b.txt
dest
  --c.txt
  --d.txt
    src
      --a.txt
      --b.txt
```

The command `copy src dest` does not do this -- it copies `a.txt` and `b.txt` into `dest` instead of the `src` folder itself.

Nor does it work as `xcopy /e src dest`.

Is there a command that does this using built in tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
xcopy /e src dest\src\
```

You need to tell xcopy to create a directory under the dest.

If you really hate typing src twice and you have rsync installed, the following will do what you want:

```
rsync -a dir1 dir2/
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html). Specifically, with the /E flag.

```
robocopy /e src dest\src
```

Comment: Did you actually try? The end result is no different than executing `xcopy /e src dest`.

Comment: Robocopy is a replacement for xcopy. It has a lot more capabilities (like multithreading, on newer Windows versions) and especially if working with long file names is much preferable. Yes, xcopy might work, but robocopy is better moving forward. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy#Features for details on why it's better than xcopy.

Comment: The issue is not `xcopy` vs `robocopy`, the issue is which one copies the folder?  I edited your answer to provide a working example -- it is required to provide the destination folder.

Comment: I won't argue about `robocopy` being a more powerful tool. The question was edited, but running `robocopy /e src dest` wouldn't create a `src` directory inside `dest`, unless you explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 1):

*The question is tagged with `cmd.exe` but PowerShell is included standard since Windows 7*

In PowerShell, this can be done easily as:

```
Copy-Item -Recurse src dest
```

or, shorter but the same:

```
cp -r src dest
```